Copy Duplicates based on specific columns and pathem to another sheet
I'm trying to find a Office script (preferably) or VBA that concats the columns: NUMBER,RECORDS,SITE,LC,DESC so it becomes a unique id. Then I'd like to the find the duplicate values of that unique id and return the duplicates value and copies the whole row into another existing blank worksheet.
Dataset



NUMBER
Records
ID1
Site
LC
Desc
ID2




100103
23019
1
MAIL1
LOCK
HOUSE
A


200103
23019
2
MAIL2
DOCK
HOUSE
B


100103
23019
3
MAIL1
LOCK
HOUSE
C


100103
23019
4
MAIL4
DOCK
HOUSE
D


200103
23019
5
MAIL2
DOCK
HOUSE
E


100103
23019
6
MAIL6
DOCK
HOUSE
F



Result



NUMBER
Records
ID1
Site
LC
Desc
ID2




100103
23019
1
MAIL1
LOCK
HOUSE
A


100103
23019
3
MAIL1
DOCK
HOUSE
C


200103
23019
2
MAIL2
LOCK
HOUSE
B


200103
23019
5
MAIL2
DOCK
HOUSE
E



Here's a post that solves the problem but now I'm trying to find a way to concat specific columns and then returning the whole row for duplicate values

The main logic is same as privous answer.

The 2nd parameter is introduced for findDuplicateRows().
Extracting columns for duplicate check section is changed to concate the key from selected cols.

function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  const Sheet1 = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
  const Sheet2 = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet2");
  const dataRng = Sheet1.getRange("A1").getSurroundingRegion()
  const dataVals = dataRng.getValues();

  // Extracting columns for duplicate check
  const keyCols = "1|2|4|5|6"; // modify as needed
  const colIndex = keyCols.split("|").map(c => Number(c) - 1);
  const mergedRows: string[] = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < dataVals.length; i++) {
    const row = dataVals[i];
    const mergedRow = colIndex.map(idx => row[idx]).join("|");
    mergedRows.push(mergedRow);
  }

  const dupVals = findDuplicateRows(mergedRows, dataVals);
  if (dupVals) {
    const rowCnt = dupVals.length;
    const colCnt = dupVals[0].length;
    Sheet2.getRange().clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.all);
    Sheet2.getRange("A1").getAbsoluteResizedRange(rowCnt, colCnt).setValues(dupVals);
  } else {
    console.log("No duplicated data")
  }
}

function findDuplicateRows(mergedRows: string[], dataVals: (string | boolean | number)[][]): (string | boolean | number)[][] {
  const duplicateRows: (string | boolean | number)[][] = [];
  const foundRows: Set<string> = new Set();

  for (let i = 0; i < mergedRows.length; i++) {
    const row = mergedRows[i];

    if (!foundRows.has(row)) {
      for (let j = i + 1; j < mergedRows.length; j++) {
        if (row === mergedRows[j]) {
          duplicateRows.push(dataVals[i]); // Add the entire row
          foundRows.add(row);
          break;
        }
      }
    } else {
      duplicateRows.push(dataVals[i]);
    }
  }
  return duplicateRows;
}


This works perfectly!! Thank you! By the way, do you know why when it pastes the duplicates onto the new worksheet, some of the data formatting is weird. For example,  it should be 0000001 but instead it ignores the 0 and just formats it as 1?

setValues resets cells' formatting to General. 0000001 shows as 1.
